# How to display data in a child component from a shared service based on user click on an object in a parent component?

Tags: angular

First off, I'll start with an overview so it's easier to understand my problem.

I have a `projects` page which lists multiple `project` objects fetched from the back-end using Spring Boot RESTcontroller and database. Each `project` can have multiple `module` objects.

**Here's Project.ts**:

```
import { Module } from './module';

export class Project {

    projectId: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    module: Module[];

}
```

**And Module.ts**:

```
import { Project } from './project';
import { TestCase } from './test-case';

export class Module {

    moduleId: number;
    project: Project;
    name: string;
    createdBy: string;
    referenceDocument: string;
    testCase: TestCase[];

}
```

So, the entity structure is clear, I hope.

Now, the user can click on a table row on the projects page. That click will fetch the `project` object and send it to a different component (`searchModules` component) which is designed for searching `modules` related to the clicked `project`. After the user clicks on a project, the URL should change to the `searchModules` HTML template where all modules related to that project will be displayed.

**Here are the components and their HTML templates:**

**search-modules.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Module } from '../module';
import { Project } from '../project';
import { ProjectService } from '../project.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-modules',
  templateUrl: './search-modules.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-modules.component.css']
})
export class SearchModulesComponent implements OnInit {

  projectModules: Module[];
  errorMessage: any;
  public project: Project;

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  receiveAndSetClickedProject(project: Project) {
    console.log("In Search Component Module: ", this.project);
    this.project = project;
  }

  findModulesForProject(): void {
    console.log("Finding modules for Project: ", this.project, " in SearchModules...")
    this.projectService.findModulesByProject(this.project).subscribe(responseData => {
      this.projectModules = responseData;
      console.log(this.projectModules);
      if (this.projectModules.length == 0)
        alert("This project doesn't have a module yet.")
    }, error => 
    {
      this.errorMessage = error;
      window.alert(this.errorMessage);
    })
  }

}
```

**search-modules.component.html**

```
<div>
  <br />
  <div class="card" (click)="findModulesForProject()">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4 *ngFor="let module of projectModules"> Modules in Project: {{module.project.name}}</h4>
      <div class="col-md-7 float-right"></div>
      <a [routerLink]="['/modulesForm']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" class="btn btn-outline-primary"
        style="float: right;"> + New Module</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Module ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Module Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Project</th>
            <th scope="col">Reference Document</th>
            <th scope="col">Created By</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let module of projectModules">
            <td>{{module.moduleId}}</td>
            <td>{{module.name}}</td>
            <td>{{module.project.name}}</td>
            <td>{{module.referenceDocument}}</td>
            <td>{{module.createdBy}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<app-project (sendProject)="receiveAndSetClickedProject($event)"></app-project>
```

**project.component.ts**

```
<div>
  <br />
  <div class="card" (click)="findModulesForProject()">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4 *ngFor="let module of projectModules"> Modules in Project: {{module.project.name}}</h4>
      <div class="col-md-7 float-right"></div>
      <a [routerLink]="['/modulesForm']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" class="btn btn-outline-primary"
        style="float: right;"> + New Module</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Module ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Module Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Project</th>
            <th scope="col">Reference Document</th>
            <th scope="col">Created By</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let module of projectModules">
            <td>{{module.moduleId}}</td>
            <td>{{module.name}}</td>
            <td>{{module.project.name}}</td>
            <td>{{module.referenceDocument}}</td>
            <td>{{module.createdBy}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<app-project (sendProject)="receiveAndSetClickedProject($event)"></app-project>
```

**project.component.html**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from '../project';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProjectService } from '../project.service';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Module } from '../module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  project: Project = new Project();
  listOfAllProjects: Project[];
  listOfModulesByProject: Module[];
  errorMessage: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, private projectService: ProjectService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService.findAllProjects().subscribe(responseData => 
      {
        this.listOfAllProjects = responseData;
      }, error => 
      {
        this.errorMessage = error;
        window.alert(this.errorMessage);
      })
  }

  updateProject(): void {
    // this should call ProjectFormUpdateComponent's actual updateProject() method
  }

  deleteProject(project:Project): void {
    // Shouldn't use this.project here. In that case it will refer to the null object created in this file.
    // Without this, it refers to the object received from the HTML element.

    this.projectService.deleteProject(project).subscribe(responseData => {
      alert("Project ID: " + project.projectId + " has been deleted successfully.");
    })
  }

  @Output()
  sendProject:EventEmitter<Project> = new EventEmitter<Project>();     // creates the emitter to emit the clicked project.

  onSelectProject(project: Project){
    console.log("In Project Component: ", project);
    this.sendProject.emit(project);                          // emits the project to the search-modules component
    this.router.navigate(['/moduleSearch']);                 //redirects url to search-modules component
  }

}
```

Here are the problems I'm facing:

- `(click)` event seems to lag one click behind. Upon first click, the URL changes to `searchModules` component but data is undefined. So in the alert I have set, I receive an `[object Object]` prompt. **How to make clicks synced to the user input and not lag one step behind?**
- In the `searchModules` HTML component, I must remove the `projects` table which is displayed because I have used its selector in `searchModules` in order to receive the `$event`. **How do I only keep modules on that page?**

**Here's the StackBlitz link for the project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uy8mff**. It is a bit unpolished, because I've never played with it before.

I have tried to make my problem as clear as possible, but if it's not still not clear, please do ask for further clarification.

Thanks a lot for reading this huge problem. :)

Comment: Sure, posting it on StackBlitz in a few minutes...

Comment: why your `redirect on function  this.router.navigate(['/moduleSearch']); `

Comment: When you navigate to moduleSearch you can pass the projectId as parameter. Then inside moduleSearch you can get the modules from backend. No nee of an extra emit here.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama If I don't use ```this.router.navigate(['/moduleSearch']); ```, the data is not passed to the other component.

Comment: @GeofoxCoding It would be awesome if you could elaborate a bit? Sorry, but I am a complete angular noob.

Comment: @AdritaSharma Here's the StackBlitz of the project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uy8mff

Comment: Sure, you should dive a little bit deeper into the router capabilities. Set-up a route for /moduleSearch:projectId. Then in your projectist component pass the projectId to the routerLink directive as argument.

Comment: If you navigate like: `this.router.navigate(['/moduleSearch'], { queryParams: { projectId: project.Id } });` Then in `search-modules` component will have `projectId` as query parameter. Use it to get project and project modules.

Comment: @IftifarTaz Thanks for the suggestion. If I'm able to execute it correctly, it should be able to fix both of my issues. I'll let you know about my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make a StackBlitz example for you. Hope that clarifies the problem a little bit. It's still very simplified :)

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-with-route-param-1)

In addition I add the major parts of my solution here as code snippets as suggested in comments.

1. Add a specific route for the searchModule component with an additional argument

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'project-list', component: ProjectListComponent },
    { path: 'module-search/:projectId', component: ModuleSearchComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'project-list' }
])
```

2. In your projectList component add a routerLink to each project entry and pass the actual projectId to the router.

```
<a *ngFor="let project of projects" routerLink="/module-search/{{project.projectId}}">
    {{ project.projectName }}
</a>
```

3. Inside your searchModule component use the ActivatedRoute object to get the projectId from routers currently activated route and use it to get and update the module list.

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute ) {
    this.id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('projectId'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the StackBlitz. I think I just might be able to get my project up and running, thanks to yours and the others' help. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your answer. You should use StackBlitz as a reference, not as answer.

Comment: @IftifarTaz Just offering my opinion here but, I think having a full StackBlitz helps noobs like me better understand the context and the proper steps towards a potential solution.

Comment: @IftifarTaz Thank you for the advice. I changed my answer with some code snippets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have successfully resolved my problem. It's crazy how simply things can be completed yet we take the more complicated approach.